# CURL error 35: Trying to connect to Curl on PHP8.2.3 Apache 2.4.57 on Windows and returns connection error

Tags: php, ssl, curl, openssl, tls1.2

Trying to connect to Curl on PHP8.2.3 Apache 2.4.57 on Windows and returns connection error.

Stack Details:
PHP 8.2.3
Apache 2.4.57
CURL 7.85.0
SSL OpenSSL/3.1.1

We are trying to connect to Windcave Payment Gateway.

```
cUrl error (#35): OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to sec.windcave.com:443
cUrl verbose information:
Trying 65.223.10.110:443...
Connected to sec.windcave.com (65.223.10.110) port 443 (#0)
ALPN: offers h2
ALPN: offers http/1.1
OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to sec.windcave.com:443 
Closing connection 0
```

This is via CURL.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$streamVerboseHandle = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $streamVerboseHandle);
 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, WINDCAVE_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, WINDCAVE_CERT );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Authorization:'.$auth));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

I have tried multiple version of the CAINFO and it gives the same error every time.

When I tried to check the SSL for TLS1.2, it gives the error as seen from the image attached.
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uuozs.png)

Any guidance will be great.

Thanks.

I have tried changing the CA Certificates, from the PHP.ini Setup to the CURL data.
I have checked the SSL validity and it's all still valid.

Comment: I just checked, it was connected to TLSv1.3 before. I have fixed it now to connect TLSv1.2. I also disabled TLSv1.3 in Apache.

Same error still happens.